# Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "pb/.twig"

Tags: php, twig

First day on new job

Inherited this project that uses Twig

I got the local instance running (not sure how)

But the staging environment falls down with this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "pb/.twig" (looked into: /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/themes/_soap, /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/themes/_soap/views, /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/themes/_soap/inc/soap/Toolkit/Wordpress/Timber/Locations/../../Twig/Templates, ) in "pb.twig" at line 4. in /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:232
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(150): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('pb/.twig')
#1 /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(329): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('pb/.twig')
#2 /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(419): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('pb/.twig')
#3 /var/www/staging.james in /var/www/staging.jamesandrose.co.uk/web/app/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 232
```

I have no idea what any of this stuff means.

Even the smallest input would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this is symfony then i suspect a config file is wrong, if it is not try finding `new Twig` and checking the 1st argument is pointing in the correct location. I suspect the base path of the application is hardcoded or something.

Comment: Tom, thank you for taking a moment to answer. I've got a config folder in my base, can't see any hardcoded issues. I've never used symfony. Can you explain what steps you want to do take?

Comment: if its symfony you can start here - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html, i am not that wel versed on the framework

Comment: You know, I think this actually a problem with the server, not the code,

the reason is certain pages work, but it fails to find the template

something todo with htaccess or mod rewrites or something, beyond my understanding

I'm giving up an finding an alternate root